# Facebook API timezone

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I record a list of past events to the wall of a Facebook fan page with the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'title'     => $info,
    'description'   => $info,
    'start_time'    => $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day,
    'access_token'  => $access_token
);
$milestone_id = $facebook->api("/$USER_ID/milestones", "post", $args);
```

It works fine. But, when I check the fan page, I see that all milestones have a date one day earlier. If I record a milestone with the date 2012-08-06, I see that this milestone has the date August 5th 2012.

Should I pass a timezone offset while recording milestones? Or give the dates in another format?

Since they are past historical events, I want everybody on the world see these events with the same date. It doesn't make sense to show Europeans and Americans different dates.

Comment: Which Fan page is this that you are pulling info from ? I tried a couple of pages - amazon, wimbledon and the dates I get via the api are the same as those posted on the page.

Comment: my timezone is GMT+2, I was giving only the date without the time; and it was always showing the previous day. then I added the time, T1200Z. Now it seems OK. Though, I'm not sure if it's the right way

Comment: Docs just say it’s an ISO-8601 formated date, so giving it including a timezone should be perfectly fine. (Also, this is the same format FB uses for events now.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#lifeevents